# Complicated nodejs routes

Tags: node.js

Well i have routes.js file inside my routes folder

```
    const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();
    const passport = require("passport");
    const User = require("../modules/users/models/users");
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    var csrf = require('csurf')
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

    // Controllers
    const authController = require('../modules/users/controllers/auth');
    const socialAuthController = require('../modules/users/controllers/socialAuth');
    const email = require('../modules/users/controllers/email');
    const profile = require('../modules/users/controllers/profile');

    // CSRF
    var csrfProtection = csrf({
      cookie: true
    })
    var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false
    })


    // Register
    router.get("/register", csrfProtection, shouldNotBeAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
      res.render("../modules/users/views/register", {
        title: 'Register',
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken
      });
    });

    router.post("/register", parseForm, csrfProtection, authController.user_reigster);

    // Login
    router.get("/login", shouldNotBeAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
      res.render("../modules/users/views/login", {
        title: 'Login'
      });
    });

    router.post("/login", authController.user_login);

    // Twitter AUTH
    router.get("/twitter/login", passport.authenticate("twitter"));
    router.get("/twitter/return", socialAuthController.auth_twitter);



// social, users, articles AND MORE...

    module.exports = router;
```

But then i have folder modules where i have for example

```
    >USERS  
    ----------->CONTROLLERS  
    ----------->MODELS  
    ----------->VIEWS 


    >ARTICLES  
    ----------->CONTROLLERS  
    ----------->MODELS  
    ----------->VIEWS
```

What i want to do is add routes folder to USERS, ARTICLES... so i can have complete module.
But i dont know how can i make it smart. For example i want to import routes from all modules automatically to main routes.js or somehow smartly because my code start to look messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the routes in separate files like this :

users/routes.js :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const User = require("../modules/users/models/users");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var csrf = require('csurf')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// Controllers
const authController = require('../modules/users/controllers/auth');
const socialAuthController = require('../modules/users/controllers/socialAuth');
const email = require('../modules/users/controllers/email');
const profile = require('../modules/users/controllers/profile');

// CSRF
var csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: true
})
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
})

// Register
router.get("/register", csrfProtection, shouldNotBeAuthenticated, function 
 (req, res) {
  res.render("../modules/users/views/register", {
    title: 'Register',
    csrfToken: req.csrfToken
  });
});

router.post("/register", parseForm, csrfProtection, authController.user_reigster);

// Login
router.get("/login", shouldNotBeAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  res.render("../modules/users/views/login", {
    title: 'Login'
  });
});

router.post("/login", authController.user_login);

// Twitter AUTH
router.get("/twitter/login", passport.authenticate("twitter"));
router.get("/twitter/return", socialAuthController.auth_twitter);

module.exports = router;
```

The same goes for your article routes :

articles/routes.js :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
// Some routes here...
module.exports = router;
```

Then in your main app file all you need to do is to import and declare all your separate router files :

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

const userRoutes = require('./users/routes'); // assuming the path is right ...
const articleRoutes = require('./articles/routes');

router.use(userRoutes);
router.use(articleRoutes);

app.use('/', router);
```